# 2 stereos, 1 car... Can it be done

Tags: audio, installation, scion

I recently bought a 05 Scion xA and replaced my head unit. It's a Kenwood DPX503BT. I moved it to the lower cubby on my dashboards console leaving the top empty. Now I'm wanting to install a Eincar Android 7" touch screen GPS/backup cam in the top cubby. I will not be using it for any audio whatsoever though. My question is, is it possible to run both units off the cars power/acc/ground harness? I want both units to work in tandem. One for music and phone calls, the other for navigation and backup cam. When I turn the car off I'd like them both to turn off also without the need for a switch.

If anyone can help here I'd appreciate it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is "Yes". It seems you are wanting them to run completely independent? If so, they'll easily do that. Power for your Android device will be slightly problematic, as you'll need to have 5vdc power for it, which means a power adapter. The stereo head unit should run off the same wiring as the stock head unit did, which will make that much easier. The Android device just needs a power source which is "switched", which means there's no power to it when you turn the car off. You can find those through the fuse panel and tap into it there. There's a part called a "fuse tap" which you can use to get power from it. As far as mounting the tablet, that's up to you. You'll have to figure out what's best for you.

Comment: @BS13 - No issues ... my explanation still stands. You can run both stereos and since you're not pushing audio from the one, there's doubly no issues.

Comment: So splicing both stereo's harnesses together, then hooking it up to the Toyota harness should work then? I was just afraid the greater draw of power being pulled through the cars harness and fuse box would blow a fuse. Thanks for the help! I'll post results and picks when finished